# How to add 2 columns in SSRS expressions with calculation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table `customerTrans` with two columns `order_date` as DateTime, and `days_of_arrival` as Int. I need to make an expression to display the expected date like:

```
(order_date+days_of_arrival) = expected_date
```

For example, if `customer order_date` is 12/15/2015 and `days_of_arrival` = 7
I need to show the `expected_date` as 12/22/2015.

I used the `DateAdd()` function in my expression but it doesn't work for me.

```
=DateAdd("d", sum(days_of_arrival), Fields!payment_date)
```

How can I calculate the expected date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using SQL command syntax but Reporting Services uses VBA. `DateAdd` exists in SSRS but uses `DateInterval` properties, not the SQL `"d"` so the expression you want is:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, Fields!days_of_arrival.Value, Fields!order_date.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks Chirs That working ..before that they taken datetiem as varchar so it not worked before so now i taken new column as date and assign that column so now shows the Expire date....

Comment: You could always use the `CDate()` function to convert the text date to a date you can use in your expression

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your SQL query:

```
DATEADD(dd, days_of_arrival, order_date) as expected_date
```